# Check if data is older then the current time php

Tags: php, arrays, date, time, strtotime

I am trying to check if in a database the time of a row and a certain column is older then today then to echo success but it is echoing success for a date which is tomorrows!

**Code**

```
// Set variable for the time
$timenow = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    // Start Expired password check and drop function
    function cronexec_expired ($timenow) {

        include('../../config.php');

        // Open up a new MySQLi connection to the MySQL database
        mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        mysql_select_db($dbTable);

        // Query to check the status of the code input
        $expiry_check = "SELECT * FROM code_log WHERE status='Unused'";

        // Run the query
        $expiry_checkexec = mysql_query($expiry_check);

        while($expiry_possibles = mysql_fetch_array($expiry_checkexec)) {

            echo $expiry_possibles[6] . '<br /><br />';
            echo $timenow . '<br /><br />';

            if (date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($expiry_possibles[6]) < $timenow)) {

                echo "Success";

            }


        }


    }
```

**$expiry_possibles[6] value**

```
Monday 9th of September 2013 12:46:20 PM
```

**Time Now**

```
Sunday 8th of September 2013 01:35:22 PM
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you are using a full length date, there is no need. Instead how about using the unix timestamp? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php. The comparison might be having a hard time comparing a full date string?

I've always found it a lot easier to use  `time()` as its basically comparing two numbers.

```
$current_time = time();
$expiry_possibles_timestamp = strtotime($expiry_possibles[6]);

if ($current_time > $expiry_possibles_timestamp)
{
    // Older than current time
}
```

I've modified your code below, try that out. Bear in mind you will need PHP 5.3 and above.

```
function cronexec_expired($timenow)
{

    include('../../config.php');

    // Open up a new MySQLi connection to the MySQL database
    mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    mysql_select_db($dbTable);

    // Query to check the status of the code input
    $expiry_check = "SELECT * FROM code_log WHERE status='Unused'";

    // Run the query
    $expiry_checkexec = mysql_query($expiry_check);

    while ($expiry_possibles = mysql_fetch_array($expiry_checkexec))
    {
        echo $expiry_possibles[6] . '<br /><br />';
        echo $timenow . '<br /><br />';

        $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('l jS \of F Y h:i:s', $expiry_possibles[6]);

        if (!$datetime) continue; // Skip this execution as we cannot parse the date, so we will not trust it.

        if (time() > $datetime->getTimestamp())
        {
            echo "Database row is in the past";
        } else
        {
            echo "Database row is in the future";
        }

    }

}
```

That should work, although I have not tested it. How is the date stored in the database? It should be in MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) or in a unix timestamp format.

Comment: I am using full length date because the cell data is used in a log that users can see, I would prefer it if I can do it with the full length date or convert full length date to unix timestamp

Comment: Fair enough, better off using an easier to read comparison though for your code.

Comment: do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Yeah use the code I provided, it should work if `strtotime()` can correctly parse the date from the database.

Comment: Did this help, if it did please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: the data is stored in the following format: `date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')` how would you do it for that format?

Comment: You cannot be serious, what web server still runs on PHP 4. Upgrade or get the server adminstrator/s to.

Comment: They refused to because their legacy scripts, 1 year contract so im going to wait it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes.

You can them compare if the difference is, say, exactly one day:

```
$expiry = new DateTime($expiry_possibles[6]);
if ($expiry->diff($time_now)->format('%d') == "1") ...
```

Or vice versa. There is also a procedural interface for this in the form of `date_diff()`

More info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: I saw this and tried it but to no avail, with your code I get the error as follows

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in D:\Websites\Sites\reveal\resources\sec\cron.php on line 26`

Comment: Yes what I provided was partial code only, you need to use the DateTime object everywhere. For example you can do: $expiry = new DateTime($expiry_possibles[6]);
Then use that. I will add this to the explanation, but recommend reading more about the DateTime class in general (link is already in the answer).